# Recurrence Relation for Full Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

For general n, derive a recurrence relation for Bn. Here Bn denote the number of full binary trees with n vertices. I have found out that it is be B(n)=2B(n-1) +1. But after solving this equation, the final answer is O(2<sup>n</sup>). But the final answer should be

B<sub>n</sub> = <sup>n−2</sup>∑<sub>i=1</sub> (B<sub>i</sub>B<sub>n−i−1</sub>)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dHDu.png)

How can I derive recurrence relation for Full Binary Tree so that my final answer should be this?

Comment: (1) O(2^n) is a whole class of functions. (2) How did you arrive at your recurrence relation? It seems totally wrong to me.

Answer (score 2):

First note that a non-empty full binary tree always has an odd number of nodes. For instance, there is no full binary tree with two nodes. So a formula that expresses  only in terms of <sub>−1</sub> cannot be right. Given that <sub>1</sub> is 1 (just a root node), your idea of B(n)=2B(n-1) +1 would mean that <sub>2</sub> is 3, but that's not correct; <sub>2</sub> is 0. Even if we would count binary trees with 2 nodes that are not full binary trees, we would never get to 3.

We can construct a recurrence relation as follows:

Given a root node, then either that root node has no children (when  = 1), or it has **two** children, each of which root a full binary tree. Given  > 1, both of these subtrees will have at least 1 node, and at most −2 nodes (to allow the right subtree to have at least 1 node): if the left subtree has  nodes, then the right subtree has −1− nodes (the root is subtracted from the count). If we count all possibly shapes for the subtrees given a value for , and we count those for all the possible values of , then we come to the total number of shapes for .

This leads to the recurrence relation you quoted, but it needs to be completed with two base cases to make sense:

- <sub>1</sub> = 1
- <sub>2</sub> = 0
- = <sup>−2</sup>∑<sub>=1</sub> (<sub>−−1</sub>)

Note how the recurrence expression will always be 0 when  is even, because then in each term, either  or −−1 is even, which by the base case of <sub>2</sub> means that all involved products have a 0 factor, leading to a sum of 0.

Also, this recurrence relation is related to [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). In fact, Wikipedia gives as example:

> ...It follows that  is the number of full binary trees with  + 1 leaves, or, equivalently, with a total of  internal nodes.

So,  = <sub>(−1)/2</sub> (when  is odd)

The above Wikipedia article (see also [Asymptotic approximation of Catalan Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1986247/341715)) provides proof that  is O(4), so  is O(2)

Comment: I like how you wrote the "n-2" before the sigma.  That's a great "I wish I had MathJax" trick.